# Solubility of PbSO4

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, aqueous-solution, solubility

The solubility of $\ce{PbSO4(s)}$ increase with the addition of $\ce{H2SO4}.$ Why?

I don't quite understand this. When dissolving $\ce{PbSO4(s)}$ we get the equilibrium equation:

$$\ce{PbSO4(s) <=> Pb^2+ + SO4^2-}$$

I know $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a strong acid, that will dissociate completely (or almost completely), like this:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{H2SO4 &-> H+ + HSO4-}\\
\ce{HSO4- &-> H+ + SO4^2-}
\end{align}
$$

So as far as I can see, the concentration of $\ce{SO4^2-}$ increases, which should give a lower solubility of $\ce{PbSO4(s)}$ (common ion effect). What am I missing?

Comment: $\ce{H2SO4}$ is a strong acid all right, but $\ce{HSO4^-}$ is not that strong.

Comment: Thank you. So what will happen? H+ from the acid will react with SO42- from the compound to form HSO4-, which will only partly dissociate? (I.e. the concentration of SO42- will be reduced)

Comment: That's right.$\!$

Comment: AFAIK, lead sulphate forms in concentrated sulphuric acid soluble lead hydrogen sulphate, Pb(HSO4)2, what is supported by protonization of sulphate anion. Kind of calcium carbonate analogy.

Comment: How could I know on beforehand that HSO4- was not a that strong acid? I have a table work of pKa values, and I notice that H2SO4 has a pKa value of <0 where as HSO4- has a pKa value of 1.99.

Comment: You've just answered your own question.

Comment: Thanks! In general, in what range is the pKa value of. strong acids?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_strength?wprov=sfla1, strong acids are conventionally acids with pKa< -2.

Comment: @poutnik -2?  Oy!  [Nitric acid misses!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid)

Comment: It is tight miss.